# Knockout.js How to create a unique field value for an observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an `observableArray` and I would like to loop through to achieve a table of fields and in which the user should be able to dynamically add the rows. Here is an image of what I would like to accomplish:

[image]

Note in the above, whenever I fill the form it updates/mutates to the other fields although I have my field name made unique.

```
<div class="spacer-xxs">
<records data-bind="foreach: $data.multi_records">
    <record>
        <h5 data-bind="text: $data.title"></h5>
        <table class="table table-condensed" data-bind="if: $data.fields().length > 0">
            <thead>
            <tr data-bind="foreach: $data.fields_schema">
                <th data-bind="text: $data.title"></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: $data.fields">
            <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.fields_schema">
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control input-sm"
                           data-bind="attr: {'name': $data.name, 'id': $index()}, value: $data.value">
                </td>
                <!-- ko if: $index() == $parent.length-1 -->
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="error" data-bind="click: $root.removeRow.bind($data, $parent)"><i
                            class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> </a>
                </td>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-inverse" data-bind="click: $root.addTableRow.bind($data, $parent)">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add item
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </record>
</records>
```

Here is how the fields are generated for the `observableArray`:

```
var field = function (field) {
            this.name = ko.observable(field.name).extend({required: field.required === true});
            this.title = ko.observable(field.title);
            this.type = ko.observable(field.type);
            this.help_text = ko.observable(field.help_text);
            this.value = ko.observable(field.value).extend({required: field.required === true});

            //Add validation group
            self.errors.push(ko.validation.group(this));
  };

section.fields = [{...}, ] //Contains fields array from the database.

this.fields = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(section.fields, function (field_item) {
      return new field(field_item);
}));
```

**Additional information**.

Here is a schema data from where I'd like to create my multi records form from. So a given page will have several form sections with single fields and multi-record fields such as the products list below. For multi records schema, I should be able to add more rows to it.

```
[{"title":"Untitled section","fields":[],"multi_records":[]},{"title":"Section 1","fields":[{"title":"Field 1","type":"text","required":true,"value":"1000","help_text":"Default is 1000","name":"field_1"},{"title":"Field 2","type":"text","required":true,"name":"field_2"}],"multi_records":[{"title":"Products","fields":[{"title":"Name","type":"text","name":"name"},{"title":"Qty","type":"number","name":"qty"},{"title":"Price","type":"number","name":"price"},{"title":"Total","type":"formula","value":"MULT(price,qty)","name":"total"}]}]}]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `value: name` (and `value: title` etc)?

Comment: Problem my name as a value and when I do that I get the name value. So I will get 0,1,2 etc. Note my name should be unique also

Comment: Could you include more of the HTML, so we can see the entire `foreach`?

Comment: @RoyJ please check above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the section of interest:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $data.fields">
<tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.fields_schema">
    <td>
        <input class="form-control input-sm"
               data-bind="attr: {'name': $data.name, 'id': $index()}, value: $data.value">
    </td>
```

`$data.fields` is the outer loop, so there is one row for each entry in it. `$parent.fields_schema` provides the `$data` for the columns in each row. You bind every element of a column to the same thing, `fields_schema[$index].value`.

You are going to need to [provide an alias](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-3-using-as-to-give-an-alias-to-foreach-items) for the outer loop so that you can refer to the row's data and not just the schema column specs. That will look something like:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: {data: fields, as:row}">
<tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.fields_schema">
    <td>
        <input class="form-control input-sm"
               data-bind="attr: {'name': name}, value: row[name()]">
    </td>
```

(I removed references to `$data`, as they are unnecessary.) `row` refers to the `field` object for the current row, and it is indexed (I think) by `name` from the schema.